# Fetch firebase remote config values on first login

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to fetch remote config values on first login (and not only after `minimumFetchIntervalMillis` expires), this is what i do (pseudo):

```js
yield firebaseConfig.setConfigSettings(15 mins)
yield firebaseConfig.setDefaults()
yield firebaseConfig.fetchAndActivate().then(print values)
```

But i do not get the correct config for the user, just the server default.

Is there a valid way to do that?

I was thinking about setting `minimumFetchIntervalMillis` to zero on first login and after config was fetched to set it to 15 mins but i'm not sure that's the best approach for this.

Any ideas?